# How to force tar cf to have reproducable results?

Tags: tar, hard-link

**Preface:** We have a complex build process and discovered it's working on one system and failing on another (unfortunally/Murphy it worked on the Jenkins build server, so the problem remained undiscovered for long). The error source turned out to be the order in which hard-linked files were put into a `tar` file by some external component:

`a` and `b` were hard-linked and `tar`red, while later, on extracting the tar file, only `a` was extracted. Of course, when `a` was the first to be archived, it worked, but if `b` was the first in the tar, the typical `Cannot hard link` error shows up.

Of course, we could `tar cf` with `--hard-dereference`, but this means changing a script in an external tool (which is to be avoided), so my question is different:

**Question:** Our basic goal is to have a reproducable result, independent of the system. Currently, the `tar`ring order is reproducable on one system, but can be randomly different on another system. Can we force a file order for `tar` without giving options to `tar` or splitting the `tar` call into several calls?

The systems are all linux right now, but could as well be FreeBSD or MacOS some time.

Comment: Please describe your problem. What you claim is in conflict with typical tar behavior. So you either have a broken tar implementation or a strange constraint that you missed to describe.

Comment: I‘ll try better: I check out the same `git` repo on two linux machines, start the same buildroot build, in which some package generates a hard link to a file and creates a `tar` of the dir structure with both files. Now it turns out, on one machine file `a` is first in the `tar`, on the other machine it‘s file `b`. This produces a problem in the further build process.

Comment: OK, that behavior with different order can be explained with different filesystems in use. It still does not explain why there is a problem with links unless your tar implementation is broken.

Comment: Only parts of the `tar` are needed at one later step, so only this branch containing `a` is extracted. This works as long as `a` was the first file to be `tar`red, but if `b` was in the archive first, `a` contains just a reference and the error message is the expected behaviour.

Comment: In that case. you would need to either use a tar that allows to have the data twice with a hard link or to give tar a list of files in the order needed by you.

Comment: @schily Thank you for your assistence! The problem is: The `tar c` call is not "ours". We can change it locally, but it could get overwritten on each update (`git pull` from repo). I hoped I could force it "from outside" to keep some order. Maybe I'll have to invent a workaround for our `tar x`. *Btw, funny to exchange with you: I remember your name from my first attempts to get `cdrecord` to work on my HP-UX workstation in the 90's ...*

Comment: POSIX allows to create TAR archives that have the data available even for hardlinks, but I know of no implementation that does that.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess, I'll have to `tar t` first, check the order of `a` and `b`, and if the wrong file is first, extract it manually before extracting the branch I actually need.

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward way would be to provide tar with a file list from stdin, which you can control (e.g. sort it first).

However, since you say you cannot control the tar call, you need a way to control the order of directory entries.

You can see the order of directory entries by running `ls -u` or `find`.

To make a directory with the entries ordered in the way you want, make a fresh directory and copy or move one file over at a time, in the desired order.

Check with `find` whether it worked. Automate with a script and make it recursive.

Finally run the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem boils down to the fact your build process is split into two parts.

- Part1 (which generates your achieve) on machine-A
- Part2 (which completes the build using your archive), works on machine-A and fails on machine-B.

And you can't create the *contents* of the archive on machine-B, so that has to be done on machine-A.

Idea

Add a step in your part2 build to clean-up the archive into a known order before you use it.

Extract the files into a temporary directory, and create your own archive in your preferred order, do this on both machines A & B (it would be step-0 of part2).

Alternatively, my version of tar (tar (GNU tar) 1.30) has this option :

```
      -s, --preserve-order, --same-order
              Sort names to extract to match archive
```